# Highcharts - Ignore Series in Pie Percentage

Tags: highcharts

I have a series that I would like to be ignored in the percentage calculation of a pie chart but still be shown/hidden when the legend item is clicked. The series represents the total and should always be 100%. If I set visible to false for the series it is initially hidden in the chart and the legend item is greyed out. However, clicking the legend item shows the series with the calculated percentage. It seems like I need another series behind the values I would like to be calculated and displayed, that's always 100%, any ideas?

Thanks!

***Chart Config***

```
    vm.installationResultsConfig = {
      options: {
        exporting: {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          filename: 'installation-results'
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        navigation: {
          buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        chart: {
          backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
          borderColor: '#eee',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          plotShadow: false,
          height: 440
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Installation Results',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'top'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            center: ['50%', '55%'],
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          layout: 'vertical',
          x: -8,
          y: 30,
          labelFormatter: function () {
            if(this.name === 'All Vehicles') {
              this.percentage = 100;
            }
            return '<span>' + this.name + '</span><br />' +
            '<span>' + this.dataLabels.count + '</span><br />' +
            '<span>' + $filter('number')(this.percentage) + '%</span>';
          },
          useHTML: true,
          itemMarginTop: 5,
          itemMarginBottom: 5
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Installation Results',
        innerSize: '70%',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'All Vehicles', // should be ignored and alway render as 100%
            y: chartData.allVehicles,
            color: '#999999',
            dataLabels: {
              count: $filter('number')(chartData.allVehicles)
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Successful',
            y: chartData.successful,
            color: '#50CF63',
            dataLabels: {
              count: $filter('number')(chartData.successful)
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Failed',
            y: chartData.failed,
            color: '#F22F1D',
            dataLabels: {
              count: $filter('number')(chartData.failed)
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Not Attempted',
            y: chartData.notAttempted,
            color: '#296499',
            dataLabels: {
              count: $filter('number')(chartData.notAttempted)
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `percentage` property will affect all pie slices in series. In that situation, you can create custom percentage property, which will be calculated based only on visible slices that are not `'All Vehicles'` slice. Take a look at the example below. Also, I think that the `labelFormatter` function is not the right place to make calculations but I only wanted to show you the idea.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g1hw761h/